# Java's getDate returns wrong date

Tags: java, android, date, parsing, getdate

I'm retrieving some dates from my Parse database. The problem is that one of the retrieved dates from the database returns wrong date. In this case when I'm retrieving the date 01/10/2016 it returns 02/10/2016 instead! The other dates, however, returns the correct date (which in this case is the two other dates in the log (07/02/2016 and 21/02/2016).

What for a strange reason is responsible for returning wrong date only at this one date, while it is returning the correct date on every other?!

(list is a list for the parseObjects on my database, containing the dates)

```
Date[] surveyDate = new Date[list.size()];
for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
    surveyDate[i] = list.get(i).getDate("day");
    System.out.println("surveyDate: " +surveyDate[i].getDate() + ", " + (surveyDate[i].getMonth()+1) + ", " + (surveyDate[i].getYear()+1900));
}
```

Log

```
I/System.out: surveyDate: date: 7, month: 2, 2016
I/System.out: surveyDate: date: 21, month: 2, 2016
I/System.out: surveyDate: date: 2, month: 10, 2016
```

Here I've got an image of my dates on the database, and you can see that only the last one (1 October) is returned with wrong value.

By the way, don't worry about the other dates showed in the image, they are ordered and sorted out in list.

Dates on database

[image]

Comment: You don't show how you get (or manipulate) the list. there are dates in your db image that aren't in your log, aren't you wondering about those?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that. The list is ordered and sorted, so the list size is 3, containing the 3 dates that is logged. I will edit my post to make that clearer

Comment: Have you tried using the `Calendar` class instead? Those methods are all deprecated. If you think they should work, then have you tried inserting one date into the local datastore, then immediately retrieving it? I highly doubt the problem is the Java getDate function.

Comment: @
SteinarSeim Tip: Consider using the [Android version](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) of the [back-port](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) of the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 2):

Check the time zone. The date 1/10/2016 in the DB is close to midnight.

Perhaps you are retrieving those dates in GMT and aplying the JVM timezone.

It would help if you print the time also on console.

Comment: Oh, of course I should have thought about this immediately! Well, thanks for the feedback, I've fixed it now, my device retrieving is a couple of hours before the database...

Comment: Perfect, ghost catched! I'd appreciate your vote in the answer ;-)

Comment: @SteinarSeim To prevent this kind of oversight, train yourself as a programmer to think in terms of 'date-time', 'date-only', and 'time-only'. Date-time work is tricky stuff, even more so when intersecting Java, JDBC, SQL, and database. Being more consciously aware of the data types involved will help.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to time zones. Check the time zones of your database server and the server that is retrieving the record, they might be different.

A good practice is to always use datetimeoffset to avoid any confusion.